# i wide shortIdentify "ENTER" as decimal value

Tags: java, char, ascii, stringbuilder

I'm trying to read text from a file, pick out all characters and write into another file.
Then the words shall be counted.

Problem is when ENTER/newline come into picture.

if original text is

```
first row
second row
```

It become read as

```
first rowsecond row
```

(writing everything on 1 row ok)
Original has 4 words, the written has 3 which is incorrect.

The probably quite noobish solution that I'm trying to implement is to translate each char into decimal value (ASCII?) by typing e.g.

```
for(int i=0; i< currentStringLine.lengt ; i++) {
    char curr = currentStringLine.charAt(index);
    int cc = curr;

    if(   ( cc>=65 && cc<=90) || 
          ( cc>=97 && cc<=122)||
            cc==228 || cc==229 || cc==196 || 
            cc==197 || cc==246 || cc==214 || cc==32 ) {
          //stringbuilder etc
    }//end if
}//end forloop
```

Which is basically A-Z, a-z, and ÅÄÖåäö

The issue: Im trying to make a corresponding if-statement regarding newlines / "ENTER's" but I cant seem to pull it off.
Looking at http://www.asciitable.com/ tried with 13 for "carriage return" and 10 for "NL line feed / newline"  (separately) without success.

Comment: You might as well just add a \n (newline) after reading a line instead of doing all these char comparisons. You can get the \n equivalent for each operating system by using System.getProperty("line.separator").

Comment: for some reason "\n" didn't work but instead I appended " " , cheers to you for getting me on the right track ty! =) EDIT: ok Ill try that

Answer (score 0):

In most OS "Enter" key is define by value `10` at the ASCII Table codes.
But i will suggest you to equal with literal and not the key code.

Example:

```
cc == '\n';
```

Comment: primitive values doesn't have methods in java. Corresponding wrapperclasses have. tried it; next problem: '\r\n' invalid character